# 9patch as background wraps content

Tags: android, padding, nine-patch

I'm trying to have an image fit a whole chat-like bubble defined as a 9patch. So I defined my `imageView` like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_content"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_right"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:paddingRight="11dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/orange_fruit" />
```

But it generates the following result with invalid padding:

[image: bad padding]

But If I manually set other sides padding to 0 then the result looks correct:

```
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
```

[image: expected result]

**Why do I need to manually set padding to 0dp to make it work as intended?**

edit:

Here is the nine patch:

[image: 9patch]

Comment: use bottom and right "black line" in your nine patch drawable

Comment: can you share your 9-patch?

Comment: I've edited the question with it.

Comment: your right "black line" is most likely wrong, dont you think?

Comment: @NoiseGenerator I reuploaded the 9patch "properly", these grey borders weren't part of the 9patch.

Comment: @pskink I fail to see your point here, not much confident with 9patches yet...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: Anyway, the right marker should extend down a bit (to about the same distance it has from the upper corner) to fill the bubble contents a little more. Or it would leave a big empty area on the bottom. The right and bottom parts define the "paddings" (in reverse: it's called the "content area") of the 9 patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to pskink comment, the problem was related to nine patch bottom and right guides which define where the content should go.

I modified the 9patch to look like this to solve my issue. There is no need to define padding anymore:

[image]
I learned a bit more how 9patch are working today :).

Comment: good to know you are learning new stuff ;-) but actually why "padding lines" are so long? your `Imageview` inside will cover your bubble round corners... or maybe your image is it transparent at the corners?